# Chef attributes symbols vs string

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Is there any particular advantage in using one other the other?
It appears that by using symbols, you would have a ruby friendly syntax, and some performance gains. However, many supermarket cookbooks seem to use strings, which are newer user friendly syntax. Chef document recommends using string, but does not provide any clear explanation.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Strings are slightly clearer to people that don't know Ruby because double-quoted (or single-quoted) strings are a thing in almost all languages. It's a lot harder to explain both the syntax weirdness for symbols and what they are beyond "like a string except not". And it only saves one character so we say to just use strings.

Comment: My personal experience has been that `Symbol`s are easy to explain, *unless* you explain that they are "like a string except not". If you simply explain them for what they are, a separate datatype for specific kind of data, namely a datatype for labels or identifiers, the same way `Integer` is a datatype for whole numbers or `String` is a datatype for text, then they are typically easy to understand, and there is little confusion with `String`s.

Comment: Remember a lot of people are coming to Chef from an ops background. They might, at best, know bash scripting, but that's often it. The word "datatype" is way beyond our expectations of initial knowledge :)